# Are failed ether transfers tx also written to the block?

Tags: failed-transaction, transaction-trace

When sending eth, EOA->EOA case, Is there a record in the block if the transfer fails?
I wonder if it is possible to check the case with block, receipt, and trace data..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only case where transfer between EOAs could fail is when the sender doesn't have enough balance to cover value + transaction fee. In that particular case the transaction isn't processed it will remain in the pending pool until sender has enough balances, transaction is replaced or it is dropped by miners.